# Let A be an m×n matrix and let B be an n×m matrix, so that both AB and BA are defines. Prove that:

Tags: linear-algebra

If rank(B) = m, then null(BA) = Null (A)
I know that this is true I just don't know how to use the m x n matrix and n x m matrix. 
null (BA) = B(ax) = 0
and null (A) = ax = 0
so then B(0) = 0
... but I don't know how to put this in a proof form or how to relate it to m x n and n x m matrix

if rank(B) = n, then col(AB) = col(A)
I'm having the same issue with this part of the problem...

Comment: What are $m$ and $n$?

Comment: THe question doesn't say. It just uses general variables m and n